# How to use REngineException

Tags: r, rjava, jri

I'm using JRI. I'm assigning a Java variable to R variable:'size'.
I have a statement :

```
final Rengine re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);
....
    String arg1="10";
    re.assign("size", arg1); 
....
```

The problem is in 're.assign("size", arg1);'. I want to use REngineException. HOW TO USE IT? Am I wrong in using re.assign()?

NOTE: I did enough googling.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different packages for Rengine, the first "org.rosuda.JRI"  is what you are using, and does not have a class named "Class REngineException", the other package that has what you are looking for is org.rosuda.REngine, so load the other Jar into your project.